# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

This command works well in command prompt :

```
 ]$ ls -ltr ../cmxserver.log*|grep "`date | awk '{print $2" "$3}'`"|cut -d "/" -f2
 cmxserver.log.2
 cmxserver.log.1
 cmxserver.log
```

However, using this in for loop gives error bash: syntax error near unexpected    token `|'

```
   ]$for y in `ls -ltr ../cmxserver.log*|grep "`date | awk '{print $2" "$3}'`"|cut -d "/" -f2`

 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: It's not sure what you're trying to do with your command - can you explain it? It looks like it can be simplified a lot. In general, parsing `ls` is something to be avoided.

Comment: Step 1: replace the deprecated ticks (which cannot be nested) with `$(...)` which can.

Comment: @EdMorton Yep they haven't escaped the inside backticks so the command is being broken. Best to just use `$()` which can be easily nested.

Comment: You might be able to skip awk altogether if you specify the format to the date command

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087

Comment: ...if you had a `find` without GNU extensions and needed to modify the answer given to not use `-printf`, by the way, see the "Complex Actions" section of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind for discussion of *safely* getting names from `find` to a shell.

Answer (score 4):

The whole line can be solved by `find` command:

```
find .. -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -daystart -name 'cmxserver.log*' -printf "%f\n"
```

- `..` - directory where to search
- `-maxdepth 1` - don't go recursive to subdirectories
- `-mtime -1` - only today's files
- `-daystart` - count the day since midnight, not last 24 hrs
- `-name 'cmxserver.log*'` - filenames
- `-printf "%f\n"` - print only basename

Comment: Worth mentioning that `-printf` is a GNU extension to `find`, so this won't work everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Tom for reply however it will result the files which are less than 24 hours old. Not necessarily created after 12:00 AM on the same day ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is 24 hours period. It can be fixed by adding -daystart param. I'm fixing the answer.

Comment: Thanks Mitroo but still -daystart seem to make any difference as it shows files older than 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You probably understood what you meant when you typed:

```
for y in `ls -ltr ../cmxserver.log*|grep "`date | awk '{print $2" "$3}'`"|cut -d "/" -f2`
```

But you have managed to completely confuse bash. Bash (and other shells) don't nest backticks (<kbd>`</kbd>) unless the inner ones are backslashed. As written, the second backtick is considered to close the first one, resulting in the command `ls -ltr ../cmxserver.log*|grep "`. Since you did not put a space before `date`, the word `date` is parsed as part of the word including the command substitution. Similarly, the single-quoted `'{print $2"$3}'` is parsed as being prepended to the backticked command `"|cut -d "/" -f2`.

Of course, both of those backticked commands are syntax errors because they contain unclosed double quotes, but before bash reaches the point of parsing and executing the commands, it is left with something which roughly speaking looks like:

```
for y in word1 | awk word2
```

which is a syntax error because the pipe symbol can only appear between complete commands, and `for y in word1` is not a complete command.

Backticks are deprecated. Stop using them.

If you had written:

```
   for y in $(ls -ltr ../cmxserver.log* |
              grep "$(date | awk '{print $2" "$3}')" |
              cut -d "/" -f2)
```

both bash and human readers would have found the expression much easier to parse, and bash would have parsed it as you expected.

Having said that, it is [never a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to try to parse `ls` output, and it is never necessary to parse `date` output because you can [specify a format](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) string; in this case, you could have used `date +"%b %d"` to get the month and day. (First link courtesy of a comment by Charles Duffy.)